# Sequelize: column "<column_name>" does not exist (Postgresql)

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I Try to query using sequelize into postgres database, but while querying I get the error called: column "createdAt" does not exist Where table looks like:

```
    Column     |          Type          |
 id            | integer                |
 title         | character varying(200) |
 technologies  | character varying(200) |
 budget        | character varying(20)  |
 description   | text                   |
 contact_email | character varying(100) |
 createdat     | date                   |
 updatedat     | date                   |
```

Indexes:
"gigs_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

Router : gigs.js

```js
import express from "express";
import db from "../config/database.js";
import Gig from "../models/Gig.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const gigs = await Gig.findAll();
    console.log(gigs);
    res.sendStatus(200);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
export default router;
```

Models : Gigs.js

```js
import Sequelize from "sequelize";
import db from "../config/database.js";

const Gig = db.define("gig", {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  title: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
  technologies: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
  budget: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
  description: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
  contact_email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
  },
});

export default Gig;
```

Sequelize try to query 'createdat' and 'updateat' like this:

```
SELECT "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "gigs" AS "gig";
```

Which is throwing an error

> Executing (default): SELECT "id", "title", "technologies", "budget", "description", "contact_email", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "gigs" AS "gig"

Error looks something loke this:

> original: error: column "createdAt" does not exist
> at Parser.parseErrorMessage (D:\Programming\Database\PostgreSQL\Sequelize\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:369:69)
> at Parser.handlePacket (D:\Programming\Database\PostgreSQL\Sequelize\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:188:21)
> at Parser.parse (D:\Programming\Database\PostgreSQL\Sequelize\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:103:30)
> at Socket. (D:\Programming\Database\PostgreSQL\Sequelize\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\index.ts:7:48)
> at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
> at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
> at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
> at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
> at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
> at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
> length: 169,
> severity: 'ERROR',
> code: '42703',
> detail: undefined,
> hint: 'Perhaps you meant to reference the column "gig.createdat".',
> position: '81',
> internalPosition: undefined,
> internalQuery: undefined,
> where: undefined,
> schema: undefined,
> table: undefined,
> column: undefined,
> dataType: undefined,
> constraint: undefined,
> file: 'parse_relation.c',
> line: '3611',
> routine: 'errorMissingColumn',
> sql: 'SELECT "id", "title", "technologies", "budget", "description", "contact_email", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "gigs" AS "gig";',
> parameters: undefined
> },
> sql: 'SELECT "id", "title", "technologies", "budget", "description", "contact_email", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "gigs" AS "gig";',
> parameters: {}
> }

Comment: You are talking about postgresql, why do you tag it as mysql??

Comment: isn't the column `createdat` and not `createdAt` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to indicate all field names explicitly that differ from model prop names (even if just by letter case):

```js
  createdAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
    field: 'createdat',
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
    field: 'updatedat'
  },
```